# .NET Core EF Scaffolding throws unable to find provider assembly 'Source=localhost'

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, .net-core, scaffolding

I'm using core 3 and I have included below packages to my project

```
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design": "5.0.7",
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "5.0.7",
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": ""5.0.7""
```

And here is my connection string and I have tested the connection before and it succeeded

```
  "ConnectionStrings": { "bikeStore": "Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=BikeStore;User ID=sa;Password=***********" }
```

Now I want to run the Scaffold command as below

```
Scaffold-DbContext Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=BikeStore;User ID=sa;Password=***********Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Data
```

And I got below error

```
Build started...
Build succeeded.
Unable to find provider assembly 'Source=localhost'. Ensure the name is correct and it's referenced by the project.
```

Here's the Server Explorer and how I connected to my db

[image]

What is wrong with my approach?

Comment: Could you try replacing `Data Source` with `Server` in your connection string?

Comment: I tried now it shows this , not sure what does it mean 'cmdlet Scaffold-DbContext at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
Provider: ' what shall i write for provider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace `Data Source` with `Server` and provide the provider flag:

```sh
Scaffold-DbContext -Connection "Server=localhost;Initial Catalog=BikeStore;User ID=sa;Password=***********;" -Provider Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Data
```

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 3.1.31

Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 3.1.31

Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools 3.1.31

dotnet ef Scaffold-DbContext "Server=.; Initial Catalog=CourseDB;User ID=sa; Password=sa;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models